# Where should I put this JavaScript code ... the Drupal way?

Tags: javascript

[I´ve read](http://drupal.org/node/102787) that you can create a mini module to limit comments length.
I´ts cool, and it´s working, but I need to add to it some JS so it tells you how many characters you have left.

So I´ve found some easy thing to do ([via Google](http://www.virtuosomaster.com/tutorials/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-a-textarea-witch-character-counter)):

Put this inside your head tag:

```
<script language=”javascript”>
function limit(what,chars,counter) {
if (what.value.length > chars) {
what.value=what.value.substr(0,chars);
alert(‘You exceed to ‘ + chars + ‘chars!’);
}
counting = (chars – what.value.length);
c = document.getElementById(counter);
c.innerHTML = counting;
}
</script>
```

And put this in your body:

```
<label for=”text”><strong>Text</strong></label> ¦ Chars left: <span id=”count1″>500</span></p>
<textarea name=”[1][3][t]” rows=”10″ cols=”50″ onkeyup=”limit(this,500,’count1′);” onkeydown=”limit(this,500,’count1′);” onblur=”limit(this,500,’count1′);” onfocus=”limit(this,500,’count1′);”></textarea>
```

The thing is that I should add that inside the textarea of the comment body. [As you can see](http://www.virtuosomaster.com/tutorials/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-a-textarea-witch-character-counter), the code works, but how do I make it work the Drupal way?

I need only to limit comment length.

Thanks for your help!
Rosamunda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply use the [Maxlength](http://drupal.org/project/maxlength) module that does exactly what you want already pre-packaged?

Otherwise, I would either write a custom module and use [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) and `hook_form_alter()`, or use them in your template.php file without having to write a module.

If you're stumped, and want to know how to do it, why don't you download the Maxlength module and analyse how it is written to clarify the processes involved?

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your answer, but it won´t work on comments, just on CCK fields...

Comment: Anyway, I have trouble with the second part of the code, whare should I put it to modify the comment form output?

Comment: I would stick it into a custom module or your template.php file. You should be able to use the hook_form_alter - use prefix to add things before the form (labels chars left etc ..), use the attributes like so to add onkeyup, onkeydown functiosn to the field itself.$form['field_name]['#attributes'] = array('onkeyup' => array('jadajada ...')...);
  }